# Can you use "\" in a dictionary inside Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, backslash, vigenere

I'm creating a variation of the vigenere cipher using all the ASCII characters using a dictionary. The first few lines are okay, but then I get an error for the value 3.
`vigenereDictionary = { "@": "0", "%": "1", "+": "2", "\": "3", "/": "4", ...` 
I want to have it so that when a user types \ it will output/take the value 3, however, I understand backslash is a special character, is there any way to implement this.

Comment: It's an escape character for a string, try using `"\\"`, which escapes the backslash itself.

Comment: Thank you! I am relatively new to programming and feel a little out of depth so despite being a relatively simple question, couldn't figure it out.
(how do I set your comment as the answer?)

Answer (score 0):

"
It's an escape character for a string, try using "\", which escapes the backslash itself. – ChrisOram
"